# Multiple assignment of a single bitmap object using new keyword

Tags: c#, bitmap, compact-framework

I have two different logic design in a single form (using C#). They are as follow:

First:

```
//Declaration is only one time
Bitmap a;

//This part of the code will be called many times
reload()
{
    if(z==1)
    {
        //x and y are just strings representing the image path
        a = new Bitmap(x);
        pictureBox1 = a;
    }
    else
    {
        a = new Bitmap(y);
        pictureBox1 = a;
    }
}
```

Second:

```
//Declaration is only one time
Bitmap a;
Bitmap b;

a = new Bitmap(x);
b = new Bitmap(y);

//This part of the code will be called many times
reload()
{
    if(z==1)
    {
        //x and y are just strings representing the image path
        pictureBox1 = a;
    }
    else
    {
        pictureBox1 = b;
    }
}
```

My question is which one is more memory efficient? I am developing for an embedded system (wince 6.0, CF 3.5) where memory is limited, and I need to deal with alot of images in a single form (method two will cause me to declare alot of Bitmap objects).

Please advice, thanks.

Comment: well, the second one you create 2 Bitmaps and only use/assign 1, so you first example is the clear winner, you could just assign the `new Bitmap(a/b)` to the picturebox directly and remove that Bitmap instance to avoid a case where the control holds a reference and wont get cleaned up, trust me I know the pains of CF and bitmaps, LOL

Comment: Also if to compile all you code into its own dll, and reference it in your application it will allocate that dll in its own memory space and give you a bity more freedom, http://blogs.msdn.com/b/robtiffany/archive/2009/04/09/memmaker-for-the-net-compact-framework.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming these are sizable enough `Bitmap`s, for memory efficiency, the first is better. It does the same job while allowing there to be  one instance of `Bitmap` instead of two.

Now the question becomes, would you prefer to take the memory overhead and avoid instantiating them repeatedly? I find often in embedded systems you are very limited in both RAM and CPU time, and it really depends on what you're doing whether you'd rather use RAM to save CPU time or vice-versa.

For another example opposite yours, I once coded an embedded music synthesizer in school. CPU time was of the essence. So say I want to create a smooth tone. It is better for that to just jam an envelope into RAM to sample from than to calculate sine values.

Comment: Icic, currently RAM is a more crucial resource compared to the CPU time. I am currently using the first method in my development as the second method would require me to create maybe 4 times more bitmap object.
But I am just worried multiple instantiation of a single Bitmap object will cause memory leaking, but according to you, it won't right?

Comment: I imagine it shouldn't.

Comment: Okay, thanks. I will proceed with method 1, and will update here if I encounter any issues, for now I consider this thread solved.